# Python Perforce - p4 add everything in a folder

Tags: python, addition, wildcard, perforce

I am writing a script that will add anything that isn't on the depot already.  I want to just be able to give it a directory and have it add anything in that directory / sub folders.  For other commands I am able to input the path and just put a wildcard /... after it and it will work.  But according to perforce documentation the wildcards do not work with P4 add.  Any ideas an how I can get this to work without using the wildcard?

example - p4.run_add("//Depot/test/...") - this will not work

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a newer Perforce server (2015.1 or newer to be exact):

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/user/relnotes.txt

> Minor new functionality in 2015.1
>
> ```
> #900158 (Bug #68860) **
>     'p4 add' now traverses the workspace when given a file argument
>     containing '...', similar to 'p4 reconcile -a'.
> ```

Failing that, if you have a new enough server to support `p4 reconcile`, use that instead (as the relnote suggests, it's the exact same behavior and code path -- I actually felt a little silly when I realized how easy it was to just repurpose it for `add`).  ;)

Comment: Ok so I updated to 2017 and the add still does nothing.  I tried p4.run('reconcile', '-a', '//depot/test/...') - that also did not work.  It told me no files to reconcile.  Now if i specify the exact file instead of doing ... then it will open it for add...

Comment: Here it is working:  

```C:\Perforce\test>p4 add //stream/main/...
//stream/main/anewfile#1 - opened for add
//stream/main/anothernewfile#1 - opened for add```

I suspect this is some sort of basic usage problem where your client mapping is mixed up somehow and when you specify the exact file it's as a local path that doesn't map to //depot/test.  Feel free to post on forums.perforce.com with the exact command output and I can tell you how to change the mapping to do what you want.  :)